# Tkinter: maintaining button distance when resizing window

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

I am switching the layout manager for my tkinter GUI. I was using place instead of grid  because it was easier for me in the first place, altough I knew it would not be very compatible. Now I noticed that while using the GUI on another screen resolution.

My example program can you find under the text together with my desired layout. I have configured my grid with `rowconfigure()` and `columnconfigure()`. One of my problems now is, that if I resize my window, all of my buttons do not have the same size. I think it is because of the number of rows which have to be distributed on the whole window. Is this just how you grid works or can I set something like a "maxpadding"? My second problem is, when my buttons are much higher than my labels on the right side, all of my labels get a very big padding to each other. How can I avoid that? The only thing I could imagine would be adding padding rows.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("GUI-TEST")
root.geometry("1200x600")
#root.resizable(height=False, width=False)

 
#frame = tk.Frame(root)


root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(8, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(9, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(11, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(12, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(13, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(14, weight=1)

#configure column size
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)

#Creating Labels
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Label1")
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Label2")
label3 = tk.Label(root, text="Label3")
label4 = tk.Label(root, text="Label4")
label5 = tk.Label(root, text="Label5")
label6 = tk.Label(root, text="Label6")
label7 = tk.Label(root, text="Label7")
label8 = tk.Label(root, text="Label8")
label9 = tk.Label(root, text="Label9")
label10 = tk.Label(root, text="Label10")
label11 = tk.Label(root, text="Label11")
label12 = tk.Label(root, text="Label12")
label13 = tk.Label(root, text="Label13")
label14 = tk.Label(root, text="Label14")
label15 = tk.Label(root, text="Label15")


#Creating Buttons
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Button1")
button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Button2")
button3 = tk.Button(root, text="Button3")
button4 = tk.Button(root, text="Button4")


#Layouting
#Layouting Labels
label2.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label3.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label4.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label5.grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label6.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label7.grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label8.grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label9.grid(column=1, row=10, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label10.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50, pady= 5)
label11.grid(column=1, row=11, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label12.grid(column=1, row=12, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label13.grid(column=1, row=13, sticky=tk.W, padx = 50)
label14.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.SW, padx=50, pady=0)
label15.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=50, pady=0, rowspan=1)

#Layouting Buttins
button1.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W, padx=50, pady= 10)
button2.grid(column=0, row= 3, sticky=tk.W, padx=50, pady= 10)
button3.grid(column=0, row= 4, sticky=tk.W, padx=50, pady= 10)
button4.grid(column=0, row= 5, sticky=tk.W, padx=50, pady= 10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: example_code]

[image: layout]

Comment: Everything you want to do, you can do. `grid` is very flexible. However, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide a drawing or screenshot of the old code that shows what you want the UI to look like?

Comment: This makes no sense, can you rephrase? _"when my much higher than my labels on the right side"_

Comment: @BryanOakley I corrected the sentence and added my desired layout as picture.

Comment: Just put the buttons in first column in proper rows and set `rowspan=3` in `.grid(...)`.  `rowconfigure(..., weight=1)` is not necessary.

Comment: @acw1668 I do not know what you mean with "Just put the buttons in first column in PROPER rows". I tried your recommendations and set the rowspan to 3 and added. Now all buttons slipped together. I added a pady but then all my labels to the left also get more padding between them (y-axis).

Comment: It means that those buttons should be put at row 0, 3, 6, 9 and 12.

Comment: @acw1668 makes sense to me. Just for understanding: The columnconfigure is not necessary here, because I assume that all columns are default configured to 1. I initially thought I have to configure every column I use.

Comment: No, `weight` is initially 0 for all columns.

Comment: @acw1668 Ok. Now I am a bit confused. I assumed that 0 would be "non-existent". But you helped me a lot. I got my GUI working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your image, I would suggest that you divide the window into two logical sections: a column of buttons on the left and a grid of labels and buttons on the right.

In the following example I use a loop to create the grid, so that the example doesn't get too long. A loop isn't required. Also, I didn't set the weights of rows and columns because it's not clear what you want the behavior to be.

The important think to understand is that you can use frames to isolate groups of widgets, so that one group doesn't affect the layout of another.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
grid_frame = tk.Frame(root)

button_frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")
grid_frame.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

button1 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Button1")
button2 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Button2")
button3 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Button3")
button4 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Button4")
button5 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Button4")

button1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button3.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button4.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button5.pack(side="top", fill="x")


widgets = {}
for row in range(1, 16):
    label = tk.Label(grid_frame, text=f"Label{row}")
    button = tk.Button(grid_frame, text="Button")
    label.grid(row=row, column=0)
    button.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="ew")

    widgets[row,0] = label
    widgets[row,1] = button

    if row == 1 or row == 14:
        button = tk.Button(grid_frame, text="Button")
        button.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky="ew")
        widgets[row,2] = button

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Those  5 buttons must be the same length as Label and Button widgets. As posted OP second images. Not the five buttons on top left.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're experiencing with uneven button sizes when resizing the window is because you have configured your rows and columns to have equal weight. When you resize the window, the available space is distributed evenly between rows and columns. This can result in uneven sizes for buttons because the labels on the right side occupy more vertical space.

To address this issue, you can configure the rows and columns differently to achieve your desired layout. Here's a modified version of your code that sets weights for rows and columns based on your layout:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("GUI-TEST")
root.geometry("1200x600")

# Configure column size
for i in range(6):
    root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

# Creating Labels
labels = []
for i in range(15):
    labels.append(tk.Label(root, text=f"Label{i + 1}"))

# Creating Buttons
buttons = []
for i in range(4):
    buttons.append(tk.Button(root, text=f"Button{i + 1}"))

# Layouting Labels
for i, label in enumerate(labels[:14]):
    label.grid(column=1, row=i + 1, sticky=tk.W, padx=50)
labels[14].grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.SW, padx=50)
labels[14].grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=50, rowspan=1)

# Layouting Buttons
for i, button in enumerate(buttons):
    button.grid(column=0, row=i + 2, sticky=tk.W, padx=50, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

With these modifications, the buttons will maintain a more consistent size even when you resize the window, and the labels will remain aligned properly. Adjust the weights and padding values as needed to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: thank you. I have several questions regarding your code: Basically, you made it more elegant, did not use `rowconfigure()` and you have used rowspan. I do not understand why it works this way but for me it seems very similar to mine. When I run you code the labels on the right side get closer and closer even if the window size offers much more space. This was my original problem, that the padding between the buttons / labels change when resizing the window.

Comment: @Zeus you can make it even better if you use `root.columnconfigure(tuple(range(6)), weight=1)`. The method `grid_columnconfigure` (same as `columnconfigure`) can take in a tuple of `int`s for its first argument.